# Macro for one-to-many splitting of Word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document which is several hundred pages long.

I would like to use a macro to automatically create about a dozen or so sub-documents based on certain rules (mainly, occurrence of certain strings in each Section).

Is this possible? What VBA functions should I read-up on? Does anybody know of any code examples which are even remotely similar and which I may be able to customize for my purposes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to figure out how to do this, even with the KB article.

Firstly, you need to put the macro into Normal.dotm... Open C:\Users\Yourname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm in Word, press Alt-F11, and paste the following into Module1:

```
    Sub BreakOnSection()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Makes the code run faster and reduces screen flicker a bit.

   ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection
   strBaseFilename = ActiveDocument.Name
   On Error GoTo CopyFailed

   'A mail merge document ends with a section break next page.
   'Note: Document may or may not end with a section break,
   For I = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard.
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
      Documents.Add
      Selection.Paste
      DocNum = DocNum + 1
      strNewFileName = Replace(strBaseFilename, ".do", "_" & Format(DocNum, "000") & ".do")
     ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\Destination\" & strNewFileName
     ActiveDocument.Close
      ' Move the selection to the next section in the document.
     Application.Browser.Next
   Next I
   Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
   End

CopyFailed:
    'MsgBox ("No final Section Break in " & strBaseFilename)
    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End
End Sub
```

Save the Normal.dotm file.

Executing this code will split a document made up of multiple sections into multiple documents in the C:\Destination directory and then close down Word.

You can execute this from the command line via:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" /mBreakOnSection "C:\Path to Source\Document with multiple sections.doc"
```

To process all the .doc files in a directory, create a batch file as follows, and execute it:

```
@ECHO off
set "dir1=C:\Path to Source"
echo running
FOR %%X in ("%dir1%\*.doc") DO "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" /mBreakOnSection "%%~X"
echo Done
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub SplitFromSectionBreak()
'use this to split document from section break


   Dim i
   Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'------ count how much section in document---------
   MsgBox (ActiveDocument.Sections.count - 1 & " Sections Found In This Document")
'-------set path where file to save----------------
   Dim path As String
   path = InputBox("Enter The Destination Folder You Want To Save Files. ", "Path", "C:\Users\Ashish Saini\Desktop\Section Files\")

   For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.count - 1
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^b"
    .Forward = False
    .Execute
    .Text = ""
    End With

    Selection.Extend

    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^b"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
    .Text = ""

    End With
        Selection.Copy
        Documents.Add
        Selection.Paste
        Call Del_All_SB
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        If Dir(path) = "" Then MkDir path  'If path doesn't exist create one

        ChangeFileOpenDirectory path

        DocNum = DocNum + 1
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:="Section_" & DocNum & ".doc"
        ActiveDocument.Close

    Next i
    path = "c:\"
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory path
End Sub

Sub Del_All_SB()

' this macro also associated with Delete_SectionBreaks()
'TO DELETE ALL SECTIONS IN DOCUMENT

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
  .Text = "^12"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Format = True
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Split word document by page counter for example use 50 to steps

```
Sub Spliter(PartStep)
    If IsEmpty(PartStep) Or Not IsNumeric(PartStep) Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim i, s, e, x As Integer
    Dim rgePages As Range
    Dim MyFile, LogFile, DocFile, DocName, MyName, MyPages, FilePath, objDoc
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    Selection.GoTo What = wdGoToLine, Which = wdGoToFirst

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveDocument.Repaginate
    MyPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)

    DocFile = ActiveDocument.FullName
    intPos = InStrRev(DocFile, ".")
    MyName = Left(DocFile, intPos - 1)

    If Not fso.folderexists(MyName) Then
        fso.createfolder (MyName)
        FilePath = MyName
    Else
        FilePath = MyName
    End If

    x = 0
    'MsgBox MyPages
    For i = 0 To MyPages Step PartStep

        If i >= MyPages - PartStep Then
            s = e + 1
            e = MyPages
        Else
            s = i
            e = i + (PartStep - 1)
        End If
        'MsgBox (i & " | " & s & " | " & e)
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, count:=s
        Set rgePages = Selection.Range
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, count:=e
        rgePages.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
        rgePages.Select
        Selection.Copy
        x = x + 1

        Set objDoc = Documents.Add
        Selection.GoTo What = wdGoToLine, Which = wdGoToFirst
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

        DocName = FilePath & "/" & "part" & Format(x, "000") & ".docx"
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=DocName, _
                 FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, _
                 CompatibilityMode:=14

        ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Next i

    Set objDoc = Documents.Add
    DocName = FilePath & "/" & "Merg" & ".docx"
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=DocName, _
                 FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, _
                 CompatibilityMode:=14
    ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Windows(1).Activate
    ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Dim oData   As New DataObject 'object to use the clipboard
    oData.SetText Text:=Empty 'Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it
    Application.Quit
End Sub
sub test()
  Call Spliter(50)
end sub
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explain a bit more what this code is doing. And if you copy code from the internet make sure to [attribute](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=462) [it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27908010/578411).