# Attaching an Outlook email item and an excel workbook into my email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I had already code for attaching the excel workbook. I just need code for attaching an email item into the email.. please assist

Comment: What have you tried after you did your research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and copying Outlook email body with a VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907811/selecting-and-copying-outlook-email-body-with-a-vba-macro)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code (change the sheet name and range as per your requirements)

```
Sub Mail()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Worksheets("to_Mail").Range("A1:AD69")
r.Copy
Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim outMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
    With outMail
    .HTMLBody = activeMailMessage.HTMLBody
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Report Complete"
  Dim wordDoc As Word.document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
outMail.send
End With
End Sub
```